# Node.js global variables not working

Tags: node.js

I want to use global variables in my project, but they don't work and I don't understand why they don't work. I'm trying to use them in the following way:

```
global.connection=null;
function create_connection(connection) {
    connection=12345;
}
create_connection(global.connection);

console.log(global.connection); // returns null, why doesn't it return 12345?
```

Comment: Not an answer to your quesion, but an advice: Don't use globals. Instead, you can write a file (module) that exports the connection itself and you can require it in other modules. Otherwise you will always have to make sure you called create_connection once, which can lead to nasty bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript always passes variables by value. So in your case you change the string value without keeping reference to `global` object.

You could have done this instead

```js
function create_connection(global) {
    global.connection=12345;
}
create_connection(global);
```

Comment: Not all variables, but scalar types. Objects are passed by reference.

Comment: There is no pass by reference in javascript, when you pass an object you pass the reference, but strictly speaking you still pass the value, which is the copy of the object reference, which is different from passing by reference in C/C++